# How do I align the Keyboard accelerator text to the right in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

```
<Grid>
        <Button Content="Button1">
            <Button.Flyout>
                <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 1">
                        <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                            <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Number1" Modifiers="Control"/>
                        </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 2">
                        <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                            <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Number2" Modifiers="Control,Menu"/>
                        </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>
                </MenuFlyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

The keyboard accelerator text is aligned to the left as shown in the image below:

[image: The keyboard accelerator text is aligned to the left]

Is there anyway I can align the keyboard accelerator text to the right as shown in the Google chrome menu?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KeyboardAccelerator have a content presenter in the style of MenuFlyoutItem, so we could change the default style of MenuFlyoutItem to adjust the text location of KeyboardAccelerator. Please refer to the following steps.

Open **generic.xaml**, find the default MenuFlyoutItem style whose key is **MenuFlyoutItemRevealStyle**, copy this style and paste to **App.xaml**. Besides, you also need to add `<Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MenuFlyoutItemRevealStyle}" />` to App.xaml, which will apply this style for all MenuFlyoutItem.

Then you will find a TextBlock named **KeyboardAcceleratorTextBlock** in MenuFlyoutItemRevealStyle, you could add `TextAlignment="Right"` to this TextBlock.

As follows:

```
<Application
    ..>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MenuFlyoutItemRevealStyle}" />
            <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem" x:Key="MenuFlyoutItemRevealStyle">
               …….
              <TextBlock x:Name="KeyboardAcceleratorTextBlock"
                                       ……
                                       TextAlignment="Right"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />   
                ……
             </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>


    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the all and some new control in the XAML Control Gallery, search this application on the Microsoft store and we will get it. also you can refer "Windows sample toolkit" which is also available on store.

Answer to your question : you can check menu flyouts control from XAML control gallery. you will also get code there